# How to reduce Xcode link time?

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

When I add a new line (just type a enter) in xxx.m file and run Xcode again (command + R). Xcode spend 40+ seconds to build my project.

[image]

but I found Link takes a lot of time, 89%. What I should do for reducing link time?